# Angularjs ng-repeat not to display on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have following example of ng-repeat which works fine.

```
 Name: <input ng-model="search.name"/>
    Phone: <input ng-model="search.phone"/>
    Secret: <input ng-model="search.secret"/>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{name: search.name, phone: search.phone}">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{user.secret}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This loads table when page is loaded. What I am trying to do is that when page is loaded not to display the table instead when value in the name box is entered to just show the results. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about `<table ng-show="search.name">`? This should only show the table when a name has been entered. If you want it to show only when there are results, you will have to look at `users`.